# RewriteEngine not allowed here magento and apache2 on VPS

Tags: .htaccess, debian, apache2, magento2, vps

I've just installed Magento on my VPS (Debian 11), I must say Magento it's a pain compared to PretaShop and Wordpress, but I really need it.

After a painful installation, I run the page and I get the following:

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
> misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at info@magento.mywebsite.ie to
> inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
> performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
> log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
> trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Then I thought to check logs. So I opened the file magento.mywebsite.ie.error.log and there is a list of all the attempts, like the following:

> [Sun Oct 23 17:04:41.916039 2022] [core:alert] [pid 886340:tid
> 139973219006208] [client 51.37.89.15:0]
> /home/elliot/web/magento.mywebsite.ie/public_html/magento2/.htaccess:
> RewriteEngine not allowed here [Sun Oct 23 17:04:42.225156 2022]
> [core:alert] [pid 886340:tid 139973202220800] [client 51.37.89.15:0]
> /home/elliot/web/magento.mywebsite.ie/public_html/magento2/.htaccess:
> RewriteEngine not allowed here [Sun Oct 23 17:04:42.495916 2022]
> [core:alert] [pid 886340:tid 139973185435392] [client 51.37.89.15:0]
> /home/elliot/web/magento.mywebsite.ie/public_html/magento2/.htaccess:
> RewriteEngine not allowed here [Sun Oct 23 17:04:42.705350 2022]
> [core:alert] [pid 886340:tid 139973168649984] [client 51.37.89.15:0]
> /home/elliot/web/magento.mywebsite.ie/public_html/magento2/.htaccess:
> RewriteEngine not allowed here [Sun Oct 23 17:04:42.909888 2022]
> [core:alert] [pid 886340:tid 139973311325952] [client 51.37.89.15:0]
> /home/elliot/web/magento.mywebsite.ie/public_html/magento2/.htaccess:
> RewriteEngine not allowed here [Sun Oct 23 17:05:22.958733 2022]
> [core:alert] [pid 886660:tid 140355403986688] [client 51.37.89.15:0]
> /home/elliot/web/magento.mywebsite.ie/public_html/magento2/.htaccess:
> RewriteEngine not allowed here

The files .htaccess in my Magento new installation are exactly identical to the .htaccess that you would find here on GitHub:
Link: https://github.com/magento/magento2

You will find .htaccess in the parent folder magento2, another one in the Document Root "pub" inside magento2. My opinion is that the system is using the one in the parent directory, magento2, since if I delete that .htaccess, the webpage would show "This page isn’t working" instead of "Internal Server Error", so the error message would be different in this way.

And this is apache2.ssl.conf used as configuration file:

> I removed the comments here

> ```
> <VirtualHost 141.146.42.11:8443>
>
> ServerName magento.mywebsite.ie
>
> ServerAdmin info@magento.mywebsite.ie
> DocumentRoot /home/elliot/web/magento.mywebsite.ie/public_html/magento2/pub
> ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/elliot/web/magento.mywebsite.ie/cgi-bin/
> Alias /vstats/ /home/elliot/web/magento.mywebsite.ie/stats/
> Alias /error/ /home/elliot/web/magento.mywebsite.ie/document_errors/
> #SuexecUserGroup elliot elliot
> CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domains/magento.mywebsite.ie.bytes bytes
> CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domains/magento.mywebsite.ie.log combined
> ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/domains/magento.mywebsite.ie.error.log
> <Directory /home/elliot/web/magento.mywebsite.ie/stats>
>     AllowOverride All
> </Directory>
> <Directory /home/elliot/web/magento.mywebsite.ie/public_html/magento2/pub>
>     AllowOverride All
>     SSLRequireSSL
>     Options +Includes -Indexes +ExecCGI   </Directory>
> SSLEngine on
> SSLVerifyClient none
> SSLCertificateFile /home/elliot/conf/web/magento.mywebsite.ie/ssl/magento.mywebsite.ie.crt
> SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/elliot/conf/web/magento.mywebsite.ie/ssl/magento.mywebsite.ie.key
> SSLCertificateChainFile /home/elliot/conf/web/magento.mywebsite.ie/ssl/magento.mywebsite.ie.ca
>
> <FilesMatch \.php$>
>     SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm-magento.mywebsite.ie.sock|fcgi://localhost"
> </FilesMatch>
> SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0
>
> IncludeOptional /home/elliot/conf/web/magento.mywebsite.ie/apache2.ssl.conf_*
> IncludeOptional /etc/apache2/conf.d/*.inc
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

Please could you be so kind to help me with this? I have no experience at all about Apache issues, then I didn't know what else info I could provide to you. Hope you can help.

Comment: You need to install/enable mod_rewrite in the Apache config.

Comment: Hi @MrWhite When I give the command sudo a2enmod rewrite, the shell says Module rewrite already enabled.

Comment: The error in your logs is for a `.htaccess` file _above_ the document root?

Comment: Yes the error is for the .htaccess, and above here in my post there is the apache2 config file. The .htaccess is autogenerated by Magento installation, that's why it's supposed to work, but it doesn't. Anything you would like to ask about any file? I would show you if you ask.

Comment: But the `.htaccess` file is **above** the document root? Your Apache config only defines/permits `.htaccess` overrides for the document root (and below), you don't explicitly state anything about the parent directory (which would ordinarily be blocked). I would have expected an "autogenerated" `.htaccess` file to be _in_ the document root directory, not in the parent directory? Please add the contents of this `.htaccess` file to your question. Do you have any other `.htaccess` files in subdirectories (such as `/pub`)?

Comment: Hello @MrWhite, my apologies, my job took all my time in these days. I have updated the question with the info about the .htaccess that you requested. The .htaccess is exactly like the one on GitHub, please see the question. Thank you, I'm deeply grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding the following line with the Parent Root Directory to my apache2.ssl.conf:

```
<Directory /home/elliot/web/magento.mywebsite.ie/public_html/magento2>
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

In this way also the parent directory has AllowOverride All.